# How to find size of atomic write for nginx access log buffer?

Tags: linux, nginx, logging, ubuntu-14.04

This [link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html) says:

> The buffer size must not exceed the size of an atomic write to a disk file. For FreeBSD this size is unlimited.

How can I find size of atomic write on my server? Is there any command to check this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the size of an atomic write to disk on my system?](http://serverfault.com/questions/599486/what-is-the-size-of-an-atomic-write-to-disk-on-my-system)

Comment: @mvillar I have read answer of the question you mentioned. It doesn't answer my needs. It is telling about the largest atomic write at the block level.

Comment: @g13 You are right. That answer is useless. (I even pointed that out when it was originally posted).

Comment: @kasperd, I have few more doubts about nginx access logs like what if I have different access logs, is this buffer size individual for each access log or shared? I can't find any good documentation regarding this issue.

Comment: @g13 That is a different question altogether. The question about what sizes of writes are guaranteed to be atomic is a question about kernel and file system, in reallity it is completely unrelated to nginx. Your second question sounds like it is actually about nginx, and that I don't know anything about. Be aware that if you ask a question about where to find documentation, it is likely to be closed as off-topic. But if you mention which documentation you read and what questions you are left with after reading the documentation, then you have a much better chance at getting an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to find out size of an atomic write in Linux myself and the most helpful reading was from this [Unix Stack Exchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68146/what-are-guarantees-for-concurrent-writes-into-a-named-pipe)

But in summary

This is from [man 7 pipe](http://linux.die.net/man/7/pipe).

> POSIX.1-2001 says that write(2)s of less than PIPE_BUF bytes must be
>   atomic: the output data is written to the pipe as a contiguous
>   sequence. Writes of more than PIPE_BUF bytes may be nonatomic: the
>   kernel may interleave the data with data written by other processes.
>   POSIX.1-2001 requires PIPE_BUF to be at least 512 bytes. (On Linux,
>   PIPE_BUF is 4096 bytes.)

So in Linux the size of an atomic write is 4096 bytes.

You can find a nice table of the PIPE_BUF size for different OS'es here
http://ar.to/notes/posix#pipe-buf.